# Watching movies on internet

Tags: lumia, video

I have a nokia lumia 925 and the main problem is that i cant watch movies from the internet,it even doesnt show the play button,mayby someone knows whats the problem,becouse i cant figure it out. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Can you link to a movie file you believe should work but doesn't?

Comment: nope,it doesnt even show to me that i can do something,theres no secondary screen for movie like you watch on pc

Comment: Can you tell us where on the internet you're trying to watch videos? YouTube, some other site? A link or URL would be nice even if you have to get it from another device.

Comment: Is this when connected via WiFi, or only using cellular data connection?

Comment: yes im  connected to WiFi and im trying to watch from this site :http://kinogo.net/,on adroid phone i can watch easily without any problems,but on nokia its imposible, i thought maybe there special programs for this problem,but i cant find the right answer

Answer (score 5):

I visited that site on my Nokia Lumia 920.

It did not show the player to me too so I went back to Internet Explorer 11 where I can emulate that I'm visiting the website with a Windows Phone 8.

The site opened and the video too. I right clicked it and it did show the flash player option.

As everyone know Windows Phone does not support flash player for videos and looks like all those new devices with Android and iOS too. Maybe your Android has flash player.

You can only see movies on the internet in Windows Phone 8 if it uses the HTML5 video player and it uses a source compatible with the device, like mp4 for example.